# Incorrect syntax near 'cast', expected 'AS'- SQL Project

Tags: sql, casting, syntax-error, project

I am watching this video from Alex Freburg: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfyynHBFOsM.

At 33.43 mins he has done some code on the server, the exact I have copied but I get this error message:

Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', expected 'AS'

The code I have tried to run is this:

```
Select location, MAX(CAST(total_deaths) AS int)) AS TotalDeathCount
From [Portfolio Project]..CovidDeaths$
group by location
order by TotalDeathCount desc
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried a variety of things but not sure why it is not working like the video above.

Comment: Should be `CAST(total_deaths AS int)`

Comment: Very poor DB structure when a column which holds the amount of deaths is not already of type int and must still be converted as such.

Comment: Is there a reason why total_deaths is not INT?

Comment: Far from impressed by that video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an extra closing right paren (`)`)

```
MAX(CAST(total_deaths) AS int))
```

should be

```
MAX(CAST(total_deaths AS int))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select location, MAX(CAST (total_deaths AS integer )) AS TotalDeathCount From [Portfolio Project]..CovidDeaths$ group by location order by TotalDeathCount desc
```

Or

```
Select location, MAX(total_deaths:: integer ) AS TotalDeathCount From [Portfolio Project]..CovidDeaths$ group by location order by TotalDeathCount desc
```